# Testing windows 10 Universal Application on XBOX One

Tags: win-universal-app, xbox-one

Is it currently possible to test a UWP application on my own XBOX (not publish, just test on my own personal XBOX One console)?

Based on MS's faq: http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/ID...

*"For developers working on Universal Windows Apps, you’ll be able to test your games on a retail Xbox One sometime after the second half of 2015"*

However I can not find any good details explaining the process for testing/sideloading applications on an XBOX One. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Technically the start of 2016 is "after the second half of 2015", so I guess you can expect it "sometime after" now... ?

Comment: In case you need to automate your testing of UWP app for Xbox One, you can use [Suitest](https://suite.st/).

Answer (score 2):

**You can now**

Good news, you are ready to go today. Here are a number of links to get you started and sideloading:

- Things to Know: https://news.xbox.com/2016/03/30/xbox-at-build-2016/
- Xbox One Dev Mode Activation: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/developer-mode-activation-app-faq
- UWP on Xbox One: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/index
- Getting Started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/getting-started

and finally, [a video on how to do this.](http://www.davevoyles.com/whats-new-build-2016-xbox-one-dev-mode/)

Answer (score 1):

### Not yet, but soon!

No, it is not possible to deploy a UWP app to an Xbox One yet (early 2016). Late 2015 was mentioned, but like many things, the release has been pushed back.

The best advice I can give is to wait for [Build 2016](http://build.microsoft.com/) where it's expected we'll be given an update on the situation.

### Prepare for Xbox One

In the meantime, as a developer, you can prepare your UWP apps for Xbox One by following some basic rules...

1. Make sure your UWP app works well at 1080p. If your PC monitor is a different resolution, use the simulator to test
2. As Xbox users use an Xbox controller (or voice or Kinect gestures) to navigate, make to test your app for proper keyboard support - as well as touch and mouse for phone/tablet and desktop users
3. Pay attention to current apps already on Xbox, those built-in and from the Store. Most apps on PC and phone simply won't suit or be useful on the Xbox. Consuming media (video, music, images) or small pieces of content is ideal.